# Can I justify and italicize different categories in one axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an axis where 1 of the categories should be italicized, and a second category is too long to fit on one line. When I use `expression` to italicize *Hemiaulus*, the two-line category switches to left justification. How can I both italicize and justify the long category to the right?

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Parameter = c("Hemiaulus", "Normal", "A long label on two\nlines"), 
                   Estimate = c(-0.17, 2.41, 0.44))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Estimate, y = Parameter))
# This has the correct justification:
P + geom_point
# This has the correct italicization:
p + geom_point() +    
    scale_y_discrete(labels = c("A long label on two\nlines", 
expression(italic(Hemiaulus)), "Normal"))
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the default behaviour for expressions is a little bit unclear in ggplot, so I think that is why your justification changes when you italicize one label. An option would be to use the `ggtext` package, that let's you interpret markdown formatted text.

You can get the italic part by wrapping the text in `*` and you'd have replace the newline `\n` with the `<br>`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
#> Warning: package 'ggtext' was built under R version 4.0.3

df <- data.frame(Parameter = c("*Hemiaulus*", "Normal", "A long label on two<br>lines"), 
                 Estimate = c(-0.17, 2.41, 0.44))

ggplot(df, aes(x = Estimate, y = Parameter)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.y.left = element_markdown())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>